# Windows 10 client cannot connect to macOS X SMB / CIFS Server

Tags: mac-osx-server, server-message-block, windows-10

I'm having a peculiar issue where I cannot login via SMB only on one particular Windows 10 workstation to my Apple SMB Server.  Other Windows 10 clients authenticate just fine.

I have attempted to change the `Network security: LAN Manager authentication level Properties` to each level, with no avail. The Local Security Policy settings that I've tried are:

```
Send LM & NTLM responses
Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated
Send NTLM response only
Send NTLMv2 response only
```

I have various errors in `/var/log/system.log` regarding these (will affix these at the end of this post), but I also tried to relax settings on Server as well via:

```
cd /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin/
sudo ./serveradmin settings smb:ntlm auth = "yes"
sudo ./serveradmin settings smb:lanman auth = "yes"
```

`sudo /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin/serveradmin settings smb` returns:

```
smb:ServerDescription = "server"
smb:VirtualAdminShares = no
smb:ntlm auth = yes
smb:NetBIOSName = "server"
smb:AllowGuestAccess = no
smb:LocalKerberosRealm = "LKDC:SHA1.12416892D38AB129C3C4E0D4362411DCA653603B"
smb:lanman auth = yes
smb:wins server:_array_index:0 = _empty_dictionary
smb:DOSCodePage = "437"
```

A sampling of the errors that are produced in `/var/log/system.log` is as follows:

```
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init request
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init return domain: server server: server indomain was: <NULL>
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init request
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init return domain: server server: server indomain was: <NULL>
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init request
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init return domain: server server: server indomain was: <NULL>
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init request
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init return domain: server server: server indomain was: <NULL>
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: od failed with -1561745588 proto=ntlmv1-with-v2-session
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: user=server\validusername
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: kdc failed with -1765328234 proto=unknown
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: guest failed with -1561745590 proto=ntlmv1-with-v2-session
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init request
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init return domain: server server: server indomain was: <NULL>
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init request
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init return domain: server server: server indomain was: <NULL>
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init request
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init return domain: server server: server indomain was: <NULL>
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: od failed with -1561745588 proto=ntlmv1-with-v2-session
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: user=windows10client\validusername
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: kdc failed with -1765328234 proto=unknown
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: guest failed with -1561745590 proto=ntlmv1-with-v2-session
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init request
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init return domain: server server: server indomain was: <NULL>
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init request
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init return domain: server server: server indomain was: <NULL>
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init request
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init return domain: server server: server indomain was: <NULL>
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: od failed with -1561745588 proto=ntlmv1-with-v2-session
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: user=windows10client\validusername
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: kdc failed with -1765328234 proto=unknown
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: guest failed with -1561745590 proto=ntlmv1-with-v2-session
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init request
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init return domain: server server: server indomain was: <NULL>
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init request
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init return domain: server server: server indomain was: <NULL>
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init request
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init return domain: server server: server indomain was: <NULL>
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: od failed with -1561745588 proto=ntlmv1-with-v2-session
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: user=windows10client\validusername
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: kdc failed with -1765328234 proto=unknown
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: guest failed with -1561745590 proto=ntlmv1-with-v2-session
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init request
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init return domain: server server: server indomain was: <NULL>
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init request
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init return domain: server server: server indomain was: <NULL>
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init request
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: init return domain: server server: server indomain was: <NULL>
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: uid=0
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: od failed with -1561745588 proto=ntlmv1-with-v2-session
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: user=windows10client\validusername
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: kdc failed with -1765328234 proto=unknown
server digest-service[18112]: digest-request: guest failed with -1561745590 proto=ntlmv1-with-v2-session
```

Any idea as to what may be going on here?  As noted earlier, it seems that it is limited to this singular Windows 10 client...

Comment: I get something like this as well...

Any news?